# Can't see terminal

Tags: command-line, themes

I am new to ubuntu and installed a theme,
but now i cant see the terminal anymore.
The font is black and the background is black.
Is there anyway to fix this without using the terminal?

Comment: Please add more information to your question. What theme did you install, what terminal are you using...?

Comment: Which terminal emulator are you talking about? Gnome Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use `gnome-terminal`. If that isn't he case, please edit your question with the required detail.

Open a `gnome-terminal` window. In its menu bar, open the **<kbd>Edit</kbd>** menu and select **<kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd>**. A window should pop up where you navigate to the tab **<kbd>Colors</kbd>**. You will see the terminal appearance options like in the screenshot below:

[image]

You should uncheck the **<kbd>Use colours of system theme</kbd>** option and the manual configuration becomes available. You may either chose a standard built-in theme like "Green on black" or build one yourself with custom colors.

The changes will apply immediately the moment you make them.